# Code causing page to render blank with PHP

Tags: php, syntax, render

So this is the first PHP script (if it's even called that?) that I've ever written from scratch, and I'm having an issue in that when it's applied to the existing (and otherwise working) page, the page shows up blank. I was hoping one of the many people who are better and more experienced than I am can take  a look and find what is no doubt a blatant syntax error. Thank you in advance to anyone that shows me the light!

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'jos_downloads_files'";
$rows = $db->fetch_all_array($sql);

foreach($rows as $row) {
    $filename = $row['filetitle'];
    $filepath = $row['realname'];
    $featured = $row['featured'];
    $id = $row['containerid'];
}

foreach ($id as $containername) {

    if ($id == 2) {
        $containername ="Incidental Information";
    }

    if ($id == 3) {
        $containername ="Monitoring Reports";
    }

    if ($id == 4) {
        $containername ="Agendas";
    }

    if ($id == 5) {
        $containername ="Decision Prep";
    }

    if ($id == 6) {
        $containername ="Agendas";
    }

    if ($id == 7) {
        $containername ="Policy Governance";
    }

    echo '<div class = "moduletable">
        <h3>' . $containername . '</h3>'; 

    foreach ($featured as $featureedtrue) {

        if ($featuredtrue == 1) {
            echo '<ul class="weblinks">
                <li>
                    <a>' . $filename . '</a>
                </li>';
        }
    }
}   
?>
```

Comment: Turn on error reporting.  It should tell you the error and line number then :)

Comment: you never declare the `$db` variable

Comment: 1. You never declare the $db variable. 2. Are you even using a database + local server? 3. what is fetch_all_array?? I just know fetchAll() from PDO? 4. Why are you looping foreach $featured? $featured can only be ONE entry at the moment. You have to write $featured[] = $row['featured']; to get an array where u can loop through. Same to $id. 5. You are looping through $featured but use $filename then? $filename will print an array EVERY TIME you loop through $featured. So for example when you have 100 entries in $featured, you have 100x the same content when you print out $filename.

Comment: $id will never be an array, so as $featured too, cause every iteration will overwrite last definition.

Answer (score 0):

As celeriko mentioned, you never declared `$db` prior to using it.  As Xatenev mentioned, I'm not sure what `fetch_all_array` is, perhaps `fetchAll()`?  Finally, as Valery Statichny mentioned, `$id` will never be an array.

In the future, it is helpful to turn on error reporting so that you can see where your scripts are crashing.  You can do so by adding the following:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

In production environments, turn error reporting off so that users don't see error messages.

**Edit**

More from Xatenev:

Why are you looping foreach $featured? $featured can only be ONE entry at the moment. You have to write $featured[] = $row['featured']; to get an array where u can loop through. Same to $id. 5. You are looping through $featured but use $filename then? $filename will print an array EVERY TIME you loop through $featured. So for example when you have 100 entries in $featured, you have 100x the same content when you print out $filename. –  Xatenev

Comment: There is some more.. check my comment.^^

Comment: Ha!  The list keeps growing :)  Think I should add it all to the answer?  Quick answer is error reporting, and get all of that sorted out.  Lots of basic errors in his question.

Comment: Ya, I have no characters left for my comment..^^

Comment: Thank you guys for the awesome feedback. I know they're basic errors...I've never honestly done this before (in PHP at least) so that's why I came you you fine folks. I think I might go back and edit the original question to explain what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: @RussToms If I were you I'd turn on reporting and fix the errors, and then post a new question.  As it is right now there won't be much anyone can answer since the code itself is too improperly done (no offense).